# Movie Clip currentFrame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, frame, movieclip

I sent a movie clip to my function. It add another movie clip to that which has a animation. As you see in output, I can see the `currentFrame` of my added movie clip (which is `"F_intro"` ) inside the function, but outside my function, it shows error. What is the solution? I need to get currentFrame of `videoMC_intro` .

```
private function playIntro():void {
    addMovieFromLibrary("F_intro", videoMC_intro);
    trace(videoMC_intro.currentFrame + " <<  ");
}
public function addMovieFromLibrary(mcName:String, mc:MovieClip):void{
    var temp:Class = getDefinitionByName(mcName) as Class;
    mc = new temp() as MovieClip;
    trace(mc.currentFrame + " _A__ ");
}
```

output >>

> 1 *A*_
>   TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.     at src::GWP_FeatManager/playIntro()     at
>   src::GWP_FeatManager()    at src::init00()

Comment: Where is `videoMC_intro` defined? As a global variable or not at all?

Answer (score 0):

videoMC_intro is probably not initialized. Is the movieclip exported for ActionScript?

More on error [1009 here](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-how-to-debug-an-as3-error-1009/):

Comment: Thanks for reply ... yes, the movieclip is exported for ActionScript